# Склеивание объектов при столкновении, с последующим перемещением за ним

Tags: c#, unity3d

Задача заключается в столкновении и приклеивание с последующим перемещением.
Не могу понять, как это сделать?

К примеру: есть объект который перемещается и допустим, при нажатии на кнопку, он опускается вниз до другого объекта, когда он сталкивается с ним происходит `OnTriggerEnter`, как мне склеить их друг с другом, чтобы объект 1 поднял за собой объект 2?

Что для этого нужно использовать?

Comment: либо добавить один в другому потомком, либо использовать `Joints`

Comment: @StrangerintheQ, а как мне кодом сделать его потомком, когда он просто валяется на терейне, а другой по нему двигается? Как мне через код задать ему Joints?

Comment: https://answers.unity.com/questions/867610/adding-joints-through-script.html

Comment: @StrangerintheQ, разобрался. Без вас бы не получилось =)) оформите ответ. Чтобы я принял!

Comment: По-видимому я не успел =)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Через `Parent target`:

```
//вешать на твоего плеера к которому аттачить. 
//И не забыть проставить тег у всех обьектов которые должны уметь аттачиться
public void OnCollisionEnter (Collision col)
{
    if (col.gameObject.tag == "AttachibleObj")
    {
        col.gameObject.parent = gameObject.transform;
    }
}
```

через `FixedJoint`:

```
//вешать на твоего плеера к которому аттачить. 
//И не забыть проставить тег у всех обьектов которые должны уметь аттачиться
public void OnCollisionEnter (Collision col)
{
    if (col.gameObject.GetComponent(RigidBody)!=null
         && col.gameObject.tag == "AttachibleObj"))
    {
        joint = miningTool.gameObject.AddComponent<FixedJoint>();
        joint.connectedBody = col.rigidbody;
    }
}
```

через `Collider: itTrigger`:

```
private void OnTriggerEnter(Collider col) {
    string tag = collider.tag;

    if (col.gameObject.tag == "AttachibleObj") {
        joint = miningTool.gameObject.AddComponent<FixedJoint>();
        joint.connectedBody = col.GetComponent<Rigidbody>();
    }
}
```

Comment: У `Collider`, нет `rigidbody`. Ваш пример с триггером работать не будет.

Comment: Убираешь эту проверку и изменяешь код под твои личные нужды :) Общая идея в любом случае правильная.

Comment: Ладно сам поправил.